# Dendrogram with Corrplot (R)

Tags: r, dendrogram, dendextend, r-corrplot, heatmaply

Does anyone have a method to adorn an R [`corrplot`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) correlation plot with a dendrogram?

Comment: I was so sad to not see any answers to this

Comment: ...2 years after, still sad :(

Comment: @Sosi - if it cheers you up, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 8):

heatmaply actually has this functionality baked in since about December 2017! See the example below taken from the upcoming v1.0 vignette:

```r
library("heatmaply")
r <- cor(mtcars)
## We use rcorr to calculate a matrix of p-values from correlation tests
library("Hmisc")
mtcars.rcorr <- rcorr(as.matrix(mtcars))
p <- mtcars.rcorr$P

heatmaply_cor(
  r,
  node_type = "scatter",
  point_size_mat = -log10(p), 
  point_size_name = "-log10(p-value)",
  label_names = c("x", "y", "Correlation")
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The closest solution I know of is to use a heatmap on a correlation matrix, for example you could also use gplots::heatmap.2.

Here is how to do it using the heatmaply R package, which also offers an interactive interface where you can zoom-in and get a tooltip when hovering over the cells:

```
# for the first time:
# install.packages("heatmaply")

library(heatmaply)
my_cor <- cor(mtcars)
heatmaply_cor(my_cor)
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

You can learn more about heatmaply in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmaply/vignettes/heatmaply.html).