# Combine ggballoonplot with dendrogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendrogram, bubble-chart, ggdendro

I have a simple balloonplot using the `ggpballoonplot` pacakge:

```
ggballoonplot(X, x = "cluster", y = "marker", size = "Relative.Expression",
              fill = "Median.Intensity", 
              ggtheme = theme_classic())
```

I wanted to know if it was possible to add a dendrogram and organise the balloon plot based on that? I know you can do a similar thing with `corrplot` as seen in : [Dendrogram with Corrplot (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228235/dendrogram-with-corrplot-r) but was struggling to apply it to the`ggballoonplot` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts later I have found that the best way to combine the two is by:

```
### Build the dendrogram
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(d = dist(x = X)))
dendro.plot <- ggdendrogram(dend,rotate = TRUE)

### Use dendrogram order to order column
order <- order.dendrogram(dend) # dendrogram order
X$marker <- factor(x = X$marker,levels = X$marker[order],ordered = TRUE)

### then use grid to combine the two 
grid.newpage()
print(balloon.plot, vp = viewport(x = 0.4, y = 0.45, width = 0.8, height = 0.76))
print(dend, vp = viewport(x = 0.885, y = 0.435, width = 0.2, height = 0.84))

## requires trial and error to get it into the right position. 
## Also ensure that xticks and yticks and labels are set to blank.
```

Alternative solutions welcome.